# Oracle DISTINCT Ignoring Primary Key Index Causing Performance Issue

Tags: sql, oracle

When I include distinct in my query below a full table scan is occurring on GROUP_WIDGET table and my query below is very slow.  When I remove distinct it is fast.  Any ideas why the performance suffers when using distinct?

```
Tables:
COMPONENT
ID (primary key)

GROUP
ID (primary key)

WIDGET
ID (primary key)
COMPONENT_ID (foreign key to COMPONENT TABLE)

GROUP_WIDGET (join table between GROUP AND WIDGET)
ID (primary key)
GROUP_ID (foreign key to GROUP table)
WIDGET_ID (foreign key to WIDGET table)
***all foreign keys are indexed
```

**Very Slow (30 seconds):**

```
SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_WIDGET.ID FROM GROUP_WIDGET GW, WIDGET W WHERE W.COMPONENT_ID=12345 AND W.ID=GW.WIDGET_ID
```

**Very Fast (1 second):**

```
SELECT GROUP_WIDGET.ID FROM GROUP_WIDGET GW, WIDGET W WHERE  W.COMPONENT_ID=12345 AND W.ID=GW.WIDGET_ID
```

Comment: Group.id is primary key so it will be unique, why are us using distinct ?

Comment: @radar there can be multiple GROUP.ids per WIDGET in GROUP_WIDGET (GROUP_ID FK) so there is a possibility for duplicate GROUP.IDs to be returned.

Comment: can you convert to explicit join and try.  SELECT DISTINCT GROUP.ID FROM GROUP_WIDGET GW join WIDGET W on  W.COMPONENT_ID=12345 AND W.ID=GW.WIDGET_ID. also try select group.id from GROUP_WIDGET GW join WIDGET W on  W.COMPONENT_ID=12345 AND W.ID=GW.WIDGET_ID group by group.id

Comment: @radar sorry I had a typo in my query, it should have been SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_WIDGET.ID and not SELECT DISTINCT GROUP.ID, I updated above.

Comment: Why would you describe your tables in a *pseudo ddl language* when there is the *real thing*?

Comment: We'd need the execution plans to really get to the bottom of this.  I'd guess this has to do with bad statistics causing the optimizer to move the `GROUP BY` operation to a result set that it thinks has a small number of rows but really has a large number of rows.

Comment: because they're examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than this:

```
SELECT GW.ID
  FROM GROUP_WIDGET GW, WIDGET W
 WHERE W.COMPONENT_ID=12345 AND W.ID=GW.WIDGET_ID
```

I think you might try using `WHERE EXISTS`:

```
SELECT gw.id
  FROM group_widget gw
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM widget w
                 WHERE w.id = gw.widget_id
                   AND w.component_id = 12345 )
```

This way you don't have to use `DISTINCT` at all.

Comment: yes I had a typo, I meant SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_WIDGET.ID and not SELECT DISTINCT GROUP.ID

Comment: OK, modifying per your comment. But `WHERE EXISTS` is your friend here.

Comment: Can you explain why distinct slows things down?

Comment: Because the optimizer thinks that doing a full table scan is faster than using the index. I don't think `DISTINCT` slows things down in general, but it appears to slow them down in this case.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to use `WHERE EXISTS` when you don't need any data from the other table - since you don't need any data from `widget` here, use `WHERE EXISTS` instead of an `INNER JOIN`